# jquery: can find element, but unable to remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got stuck here with jQuery remove method. Here's a piece of code ...

```
clearTemplate : function(contentContainer) {
  var container = $('body').find('#' + contentContainer);
    if (container.length !== 0) {
        console.log(container.length);
        container.remove();
        console.log(container.length);
    }
}
```

Script can easily find '#'+contentContainer in DOM but is unable to remove it. It has no problem with removing children elements of container object as well.
Console.log returns (obviously) : 1 and 1

Container is also dynamically loaded into DOM.
Here's a bigger piece ...

```
var TemplateClass = {

mainDiv : $('<div>').attr('id',contentContainer),
setData : function(result, images, template, link) {
    this.result = result;
    this.images = images;
    this.template = template;
    this.link = link;
},

readyTemplate : function() {
    var that = this;
    $.each(this.result, function () {
        data = that.result[0];
        $(that.mainDiv).loadTemplate(that.template, data, {
            append: true
        });
    });
    return this.mainDiv;
},

clearTemplate : function(contentContainer) {
  var container = $('body').find('#' + contentContainer);
    if (container.length !== 0) {
        console.log(container.length);
        container.remove();
        console.log(container.length);
    }
}
```

}

I'm able to live without removing this object, but it's just not right.

Comment: The `.length` of the jQuery object won't change after you call `.remove()`; it still contains the DOM element even though it has been removed from the DOM graph.

Comment: You're trying to remove the container is there is at least one? Why not just $("body #"+contentContainer).remove(); ? If there is none, it will not remove anything

Comment: ... and since it's a by-id lookup, there's no reason to use `$("body").find()` - just `$("#" + contentContainer).remove()`

Comment: I think length has to change since it's a number of entities in collection. And not length of collection is the problem, but inability to remove that item. If I try to remove any other thing (counting children elements of that object) it's working as it should.

Comment: It’s not a “collection”, it is a jQuery object. And those are not “live” like NodeLists in the DOM are, but static. You need to execute the selector again to get an “updated” object that reflects the current state of the DOM here.

Comment: Seems logical. Thank you.